# Finding the solar radius from temperature and luminosity

Tags: temperature, luminosity

This question has eluded me for days; I can't seem to solve it.

A certain star has a temperature twice that of the Sun and a luminosity 55 times greater than the solar value. What is its radius, in solar units?

Comment: I believe that you followed the recommendation to post [your question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3427757) here. May I suggest that you delete the other question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

There is an approximate [relation between luminosity, radius and temperature for stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93luminosity_relation#Core_and_surface_temperatures):
$$
L = 4\pi R^2\sigma_B T_S^4
$$

Can you solve it from here?